# ORA-00907 On a delete statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00907

I'm trying to delete a random record from a table but I get an *ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis* error and I can't find what's wrong.

Here's my statement:

```
DELETE FROM participation WHERE ROWID IN (
    SELECT ROWID FROM participation
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1
        ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM);
```

And here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE participation (
    matrEmp     NUMBER(4)     NOT NULL,
    codeProj     VARCHAR(14)   NOT NULL,
    fonction VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_part PRIMARY KEY (matrEmp, codeProj)
);
```

Comment: Your delete subquery makes no  sense.  ROWNUM=1 just returns the 1st row,  Order by takes place after that.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: your inline order by clause is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROWNUM filters data before you use it, so it won't work. For older versions you can choose a random pk like,

```
DELETE FROM participation s3
WHERE (s3.matrEmp, s3.codeProj) IN (SELECT s2.matrEmp,
                                         s2.codeProj
                                    FROM (SELECT RANK() over(ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value) random_rank,
                                                 s1.matrEmp,
                                                 s1.codeProj
                                            FROM participation s1) s2
                                   WHERE random_rank = 1)
```

If you use Oracle 12c, you could use row limiting

```
DELETE FROM participation s3
 WHERE (s3.matrEmp, s3.codeProj) IN (SELECT s1.matrEmp,
                                        s1.codeProj
                                   FROM participation s1
                                  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value 
                                  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Not very elegant, but - as far as I could test it - seems to be working. The TEST table is a duplicate of Scott's EMP table.

```
delete from test s
  where s.empno = (select r.empno 
                   from (select t.empno, row_number() over (order by t.empno) rn
                         from test t
                        ) r
                   where r.rn = (select round(dbms_random.value(1, m.cnt))
                                 from (select count(*) cnt 
                                       from test e
                                      ) m
                                )
                  );
```